Error of the slope that is more representative of the variability around the linear fit or of goodness of the fit (R2)?
I have 2 data sets of different length, one is much larger than the other (turquoise points in the picture). I am fitting both with a line with NO intercept, so the slope is the only free parameter. The fit routine is returning an error of the slope. The error of the slope (standard error) is much lower for the turquoise points than for black ones. I understand that  its due to the large sample size. However the R2 for the black points is higher that for the turquoise ones. Is there any way to get an slope error estimate that reflects the R2 behavior?


Why do you see your results as exhibiting undesirable behavior? The large sample size means that you have a precise estimate, despite the variance in the data. That’s why we like to collect large sample sizes (at least one reason).

It sounds like you might be looking for some estimate of the error variance, but that's not what $R^2$ gives you.

@Dave I dont say it is undesirable but I would like to have some error estimates based on the goodness of the fit, like R2 but something that could be directly applied to the slope (like error estimates). In the next step I want to compare these pairs of slopes (paired black and turquoise slopes) for 12 pairs. And in all cases the turquoise slope error is much smaller compared to that of the black data. However based on R2 black line is more representative of the black data than turquoise line of the turquoise  data.

@whuber yeah, I think that might go in the right direction but it is not exactly that. To be honest I am not sure that the thing, that I am looking for, exists... I need some error estimate for the slope that is somehow representative of the variation of the data around the fit.

From the comments:

I need some error estimate for the slope that is somehow representative of the variation of the data around the fit.

Parameter standard error satisfies this.
Parameter standard error uses two important features of the regression:

Residual variation, which estimates error variance

Size of the data


You want the precision to increase as the fit gets better. All else equal, as the residual variance decreases, your standard error will decrease.
You also want the precision to increase as you get more observations. Even if there is considerable variance, as you get more and more data, you start to pin down the parameter value. All else equal, as the number of observations increases, your standard error will decrease.
I think the standard errors and confidence intervals you are calculating do exactly what you want them to do and accurately reflect the interaction between residual variance and sample size in terms of providing precision to the parameter estimation.
